# 2.8 Solid view turn off transparency?

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view, transparency

I am trying to figure out how to disable transparency in solid view. I can disable it in LookDev via the node editor, but not sure in Solid...
[image]
[image]

The transparent surfaces are sitting on top of transparent pixels, but these pixels do have color information (as seen in the image above)...
[image]

I like the solid view for ease of Flat shade and other aesthetic preferences, particularly for texture painting...

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

Press Z then hit 2.
It also has options for LookDev, Rendered, etc.

Comment: Z changes to wireframe view, and 2 changes to 2nd collection...

Comment: Hm, That hasn't been the case with blender 2.8 with me. When is the last time you downloaded blender 2.8?

Comment: It was on Monday, so four-ish days ago

Comment: This is strange because hitting z to go to wireframe view is the 2.79 way to do things. How do you go to rendered view with your blender?